# The specific meaning of $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in SphericalHarmonicY

Tags: functions

The problem I have encountered is that two different reference math books have different representations of $\theta$ and $\varphi$ for **the spherical coordinate system**.

[image]

**For Figure 1:**
$$
0<\theta <\pi ,\ 0<\varphi <2\pi 
$$
$$
dv=r^2\sin \theta d\varphi d\theta dr
$$
**For Figure 2:**
$$
0<\varphi <\pi ,\ 0<\theta <2\pi 
$$
$$
dv=r^2\sin \varphi d\theta d\varphi dr
$$

The **spherical harmonic function** in **Mathematica** is defined as follows:

```
SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]
```

I would like to know which of the two plots above corresponds to $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in mathematica's built-in function `SphericalHarmonicY`? The different angular correspondence is important for me to calculate the triple integral later.

Comment: Should't the convention used in be obvious just by evaluating (for example)  `SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, \[Theta], \[Phi]]`

Comment: The range I wrote may cause some misunderstanding. It is actually used in spherical coordinates and is useful for me to calculate triple integrals. However, the variable values in SphericalHarmonicY can be filled in at will, such as SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, 10000, 10000]//N.

Comment: From `SphericalHarmonicY[1, 1, \[Theta], \[Phi]]= -(1/2) E^(I \[Phi]) Sqrt[3/(2 \[Pi])] Sin[\[Theta]]` it is clear that your first definition is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Wolfram Language uses the physics convention, like in your figure 1.

Weisstein, Eric W. "Spherical Harmonic." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html

[image]

> In this entry, theta is taken as the polar (colatitudinal) coordinate
> with theta in $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, and $\phi$ as the azimuthal (longitudinal)
> coordinate with $phi \in [0,2\pi)$. This is the convention normally used
> in physics, as described by Arfken (1985) **and the Wolfram Language**
> [...] Spherical harmonics are implemented in the Wolfram Language as
> `SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, theta, phi]`.

[image]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system):

> Spherical coordinates $(r, θ, φ)$ as commonly used in physics (ISO
> 80000-2:2019 convention): radial distance r (distance to origin),
> polar angle $θ$ (theta) (angle with respect to polar axis), and
> azimuthal angle φ (phi) (angle of rotation from the initial meridian
> plane).

For example, you may recognize the phase $\exp\left(i \, \phi\right)$ factor corresponding to the longitudinal coordinate and the $\sin(\theta)$ factor corresponding to the latitude by evaluating `SphericalHarmonicY[1,1, θ, ϕ].`

[image]

Which should confirm the statements before.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see at reference page,
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalHarmonicY.html

```
SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]
```

Returns $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$

For example, If you evaluate

```
SphericalHarmonicY[3, 1, \[Theta], \[Phi]]
```

, You will obtain
$$-\frac{1}{8}e^{i\phi}\sqrt{\frac{21}{\pi}}(1+5\cos^2\theta)\sin\theta$$

And this result clearly means your first definition of spherical coordinate has been used.

Comment: Can you explain *" this result clearly means your first definition of spherical coordinate has been used."* ?  That *clearly* may not be as clear for all.